# How to invoke API event entry source in Journey builder From Landing pages?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, landing-page

I need to invoke journey in journey builder while new data insert/updated in Data extension, each data entry - journey has to invoke immediately ? is that possible ? For that I tried with API event as a entry source

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a journey from a cloud page by invoking the journey builder fire event REST API.

See the example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postEvent.htm)

This will insert the data into the entry source DE as well as trigger the journey at the same time

Comment: Thanks, @praveen - actually dont want to insert data and tried with fire event Rest API having some issue.https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235958/getting-error-while-try-to-trigger-api-event-in-journey-from-landing-pages-using

Answer (score 0):

You can use below steps to do this.

Use CloudPages to Admit Contacts into Journey Builder
Use a CloudPages Smart Capture form and Journey Builder to admit Marketing Cloud contacts into a journey using the CloudPages Form Submit Event.

Create at least one Smart Capture form in CloudPages before you use this entry source.

Drag CloudPages onto the canvas.
Click CloudPages.
Choose a Smart Capture form and click Next.
When a customer submits the Smart Capture form, that customer is automatically added to a data extension and queued to enter this journey.
Build the rest of the journey, and click Activate to begin admitting contacts who submit the designated Smart Capture form.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_entry_sources.htm&type=5